# How to properly implement a drop-down box using <SelectListItem> and repository pattern in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to know how to properly implement a drop-down box using **`<SelectListItem>`** type in ASP.NET MVC. I have not used this method before, and I've been advised that this is the best way to go if I have to perform a 'Required' validation on the drop-down.

I've created a drop-down previously using ViewBag, and I don't think I find that approach very effective.

My example here is simple. A small app that allows the user to enter customer name and choose a country from the drop-down. It should also check that the user selects a country and enters a value in name textbox. Please have a look at my code below. It is incomplete and just a template, so please help me how to fully implement this approach. Please also feel free to use a repository if using it is effective. I'm still struggling to understand how to use repository pattern, so help and explanation would be needed on that as well. Thanks

**Customer View Model**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Country CountryId { get; set; }
}

public class Country 
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; } 
}
```

**Model**

1. **Customers** - EntityFramework entity containing a table for Customer details holding a foreign key to Countries Entity
2. **Countries** - Entity containing a table for CountryId and CountryName

**Action Result**

```
Models.EFEntities ctx = new Models.EFEntities();

public ActionResult GetCustomers()
{
    using(ctx) 
    {
        Need code to properly implement this part 
    }
        return view("Customers");
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCustomer(Model.Customer customer)
{
    using(ctx) 
    {
        //I'm thinking of calling the SaveChanges() method on Customers Entity, 
        //but please let me know if you have any better ways of writing this code.
        // something like using repository pattern)
    }
    return view();
}
```

**Customers View**
The view displays a simple interface to enter customer name and select a country from the dorp-down. I'm thinking it should be something like the one below

```
@model Models.Customer

@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
@Html.ValidationFor(model=>model.Name)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country..?..Need code here as well, "please select")
@Html.ValidationFor(...Need code here to make sure the user selects a country)
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the select list in your `Customer`

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; } 
}
```

Build the model in your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult GetCustomers()
{
    var model = new Customer();
    using(ctx) 
    {
        // Need code to properly implement this part 
        // > I assume you know how to do this, something like:
        var customer = ctx.Customers.Get(the_id);
        // map the entity to your model
        model.Id = customer.Id;
        // map the rest of the fields here (you may want to use mapper tools)

        // get the country list from your db and map it to selectlistitem
        model.Countries = mapCountries(ctx.Countries.GetAll());
    }
    return view(model);
}
```

**Your View**

```
@model Models.Customer

@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
@Html.ValidationFor(model=>model.Name)
// implement the rest of your fields
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.Countries, "please select")
@Html.ValidationFor(model => model.CountryId)
```

**Then in your post method**

1. Make sure the model is valid (server-side validation)
2. Map your model back to your entity
3. Save the entity to your database

That's basically it, you just need to fill in the blanks with codes specific to your project.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try now. Just one question, does the 'CountryId' property still has to be of type 'Country' ? If so, what are the properties I should have in the 'Country' class ? And, would you recommend automapper for mapper tools ?

Comment: Sorry that should have been an int, or the type you have for `Id`. [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Comment: I'm now trying to create the drop-down using the method you've suggested. I haven't used the repository yet, because I'm still struggling to get my head around it. I'm accessing the context directly and populating my view model 'Customer'. When I try to map the countryname from database to 'Countries' property, I get the error, 'cannot convert to string to <selectListItem>' could you please help ? I can post my dataaccess code if needed. thanks

Comment: Something like: `var items = new List<SelectListItem>();        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = country.Id, Value= country.Name});` where `country` is a variable you use in your loop. You can also generate the SelectListItems using linq, several ways to do it.